# Linux pppd - lcp config failures on debian 8 pppd 2.4.6 but works on ubuntu 22.0 with pppd 2.4.9 - CHAP challenge appears after confrej

Tags: linux, debian, modem, ppp, teltonika

I hope someone can help me

I have a Teltonika modem with a Wireless Logic SIM which we are driving using the Linux pppd daemon over a serial port and Im trying to work out why I cant get past authentication on an older Debian linux with pppd 2.4.6 (which we cant upgrade) when I can with a later version on Ubuntu. It seems the older system wants to reject "auth chap MD5" finally hanging on a "Discarded non-LCP packet when LCP not open" error. Ive been looking at the pppd man pages for hours and i cant find a solution! PPP debug output below at bottom of post

Chat file is

```
TIMEOUT 60
ECHO ON
ABORT '\nBUSY\r'
ABORT '\nERROR\r'
ABORT '\nNO ANSWER\r'
ABORT '\nNO CARRIER\r'
ABORT '\nNO DIALTONE\r'
'' ATZ
OK 'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","wlapn.com"'
OK ATD*99***1#
CONNECT ''
```

Peer file is

```
cp-echo-failure 0
lcp-echo-interval 0
#nodetach
debug
connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/wireless-logic"
/dev/ttyUSB0
115200
crtscts
noipdefault
default-asyncmap
defaultroute
nobsdcomp
noauth
passive
persist
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
user R2PUKSYS
password R2PUKSYS
usepeerdns
lock
novj
show-password
```

Debug of non-working version where it just ends after the final error, also notice CHAP challenge seems to appear even after we've rejected???

```
ATZ
OK
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","wlapn.com"
OK
ATD*99***1#
CONNECT
Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs finished (pid 3229), status = 0x0
Serial connection established.
using channel 9
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyS2
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <magic 0x9fec45d1> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2a <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xd13c8cca> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x2a <asyncmap 0x0>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2b <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xd13c8cca> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x2b <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xd13c8cca> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x2c magic=0xd13c8cca]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <magic 0x9fec45d1> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2d <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xd13c9885> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x2d <asyncmap 0x0>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2e <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xd13c9885> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x2e <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xd13c9885> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x2f magic=0xd13c9885]
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x2 <fa05d11a50d2b1b27348a897aa62ab92>, name = "UMTS_CHAP_SRVR"]
Discarded non-LCP packet when LCP not open
rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x3 <0692e9e924970fcd3bc39cf1c0ebdfaf>, name = "UMTS_CHAP_SRVR"]
Discarded non-LCP packet when LCP not open
rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x4 <a513a0bbc0a57e3769a6cf74883dc16e>, name = "UMTS_CHAP_SRVR"]
Discarded non-LCP packet when LCP not open
rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x5 <62434f6aabb3f3c981c572115fcb298c>, name = "UMTS_CHAP_SRVR"]
Discarded non-LCP packet when LCP not open
rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x6 <4e25351af6614f8d2cd4921f49186666>, name = "UMTS_CHAP_SRVR"]
Discarded non-LCP packet when LCP not open
```

Working connection on Ubuntu - same modem same config

```
OK
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","wlapn.com"
OK
ATD*99***1#
CONNECT
Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/wireless-logic finished (pid 8876), status = 0x0
Serial connection established.
using channel 1
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB0
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <magic 0x77d321f9> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x0 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x2d03c0b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x0 <asyncmap 0x0>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <magic 0x77d321f9> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x2d03c0b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x2d03c0b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x2 magic=0x2d03c0b]
rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x1 <b85176b8ba400effcb027573e0394a5e>, name = "UMTS_CHAP_SRVR"]
sent [CHAP Response id=0x1 <97247cf226529819c7d9cf5a16345f7c>, name = "********"]
rcvd [CHAP Success id=0x1 ""]
CHAP authentication succeeded
CHAP authentication succeeded
sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::2c99:da39:1484:84a0>]
rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x3 80 fd 01 01 00 0c 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00]
Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x0]
sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x0 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <addr 10.94.158.0> <ms-dns1 10.4.0.240> <ms-dns2 10.4.0.230>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 10.94.158.0> <ms-dns1 10.4.0.240> <ms-dns2 10.4.0.230>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1]
sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x1]
rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x2 <addr 10.94.158.0> <ms-dns1 10.4.0.240> <ms-dns2 10.4.0.230>]
Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Script /etc/ppp/ip-pre-up started (pid 8888)
Script /etc/ppp/ip-pre-up finished (pid 8888), status = 0x0
not replacing default route to wlp59s0 [10.20.31.254]
local  IP address 10.94.158.0
remote IP address 10.64.64.64
primary   DNS address 10.4.0.240
secondary DNS address 10.4.0.230
Script /etc/ppp/ip-up started (pid 8893)
Script /etc/ppp/ip-up finished (pid 8893), status = 0x0
```

Any ideas???

Peter

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) would be better placed for questions like this

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution to this ... it didnt seem to like the baud rate i was using .. I have an Olimex board which is a lower i reduced to 19200 and it worked fine